Ubuntu 23.10: Unable to install PHP 7.1 using ppa:ondrej/php and apt install php7.1
I'm a Laravel dev and new to Ubuntu. I have two different apps which use two different versions of PHP. I need to have PHP 7.1.x.
I tried to explore different platforms most of them are using ppa:ondrej/php However that package is not working and upon research I got this result
Not able to install php 7.4 on Ubuntu 21.10 impish version
which says to wait till the next release. I also checked this
How I can install multiple versions of php in ubuntu 22.10 version?
where instead of PHP 8.x I follow the instructions from here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-php-7-4-and-set-up-a-local-development-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04
But when I try $ sudo apt install php7.1 I got this E: Package 'php7.1' has no installation candidate.

The PPA you mention (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) only provides support (now) for LTS releases; your 23.10 (mantic) is not a LTS release, thus the PPA has no support for your chosen release.

So Can  I downgrade the ubuntu version?

Ubuntu/Debian upgrade tools are designed to only upgrade to newer or later versions... To go backwards you revert prior backups you created, or re-install. You can non-destructively re-install desktop systems, however some applications do not work well with data files created/modified by newer apps, so all application checks (ie. how each app will deal with files created/modified by newer versions of the same app) are on you to perform.. but in most cases its not an issue.

Thanks @guiverc It works fine after getting the LTS verison.
